# Can I hide certain printers from the Printdialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing

I have written an application that writes "Cut Cards" to a Zebra Printer. It passes the info to the printer as raw ZPL code. The problem I have is my employees select the wrong printer. Is there a way to setup something like a printer blacklist, so when I open a printdialog a list of known wrong printers are excluded from the list?

Comment: after looking at several other applications that are designed to interact with Zebra printers the common thread is they don't use the native printdialog anyways. i have decided to "re-invent" and just use a custom written printdialog as this appears to be the norm when using these printers. as only one answer was submitted i will accept it even though i have chosen not to use it.

Comment: Good choice Tim, your custom dialog is part of blacklist/whitelist I mentioned in the answer, because custom dialog is actually a form of native filtering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more ways:

- **Blacklist/whitelist:** Use additional configuration dialog in your application where you can set which printers are wrong. After the user confirms standard print dialog, simply throw error if printer is on the blacklist (or isn't on the whitelist).
- **System administration** (no programming, can be the cheapest):

  - Set Zebra printer as default printer for given user.
  - Rename Zebra printer (in printer properties) to something like
    `Zebra – Print CUT CARDS here!`. Employees will have hard time explaining how they overlooked this. And if printers are sorted by name, you can also this way move the printer to first/last/custom position in the list. Use this to make sure the item is in initial view (=no need to scroll the list to find the printer).
  - Ban wrong printers from printing from that PC or for given users – use Security tab to set permissions. Create separate user accounts for users or for roles (e.g. worker / manager / admin).

In large companies, no one is programming restrictions on printing to printers. All is implemented simply by setting permissions. Windows already has advanced mechanism for this inside. I would recommend you this way instead of re-inventing some restrictions on your own.